# How to tell what version of javascript chrome dev tools is running?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

You would say, "Well it's running the according version to the version of Chrome you're running of course!", but is there a way to see/set what version of javascript you're working with in Chrome Dev Tools?

I ask becuase I was trying to follow along with [MDN's `const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) example but `const` wasn't working as expected in the Chrome Dev Tools Console.

I'm on Chrome Version 49.0.2623.108 m and have some experimental settings checked.

Me trying to use `const` in the Chrome Dev Tools Console:

```
const MY_FAV = 7;
undefined
MY_FAV
VM202:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: MY_FAV is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM202:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM134:878InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM134:811InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM134:667
MY_FAV = 20;
20
MY_FAV
20
```

I was writing other ES6 things in the console earlier today like `...args` so not sure why `const` is acting like this right now.

Comment: FWIW, `const` works in 50

Comment: @josh3736 - `const` works from Chrome 20 (in strict), so yes, it will work in the upcoming release of Chrome 50 as well, in about two weeks

Comment: Also, `navigator.appVersion` will show you what version of Chrome you're running, anything before 49 will require strict mode to use `const`

Comment: Chrome wasn't auto-updating past Chrome 49 so I just installed [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) (Chrome 51) and `const` works in there with no need for `"use strict";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a way to see/set what version of javascript you're working with in Chrome Dev Tools?

Whatever your browser's engine is implementing, really.

The best you can see is probably the name and version of your browser's JavaScript engine at `chrome://version/`, which you can then cross-reference with [the issue tracker, filtered by version label](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/list?can=1&q=label%3AHarmony).

[image: screenshot]

If you're asking whether certain features are implemented, you're probably best off looking at [compatibility tables](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const) or searching for the specific features in [the issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/list?can=1&q=label%3AHarmony+const) or [other databases](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const).